# org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter generateDdl Not Working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring 3.* using JPA hibernate impl and I've set the Spring org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter generateDdl to true, but I don't see it actually doing anything.  I swap it to false and I get the same output in my log.  Anyone know what this setting is supposed to do?  Its not generating the ddl.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="api" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${jpa.vendor.showsql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${jpa.vendor.generate.statistics}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${cache.use.secondLevel}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${cache.use.query}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="${console.show.sql}" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use an IDE that has good Spring/XML support (notably IntelliJ IDEA), you can view what each property should do (in IDEA put the cursor on it and press CTRL+Q). The specc says:

> Set whether to generate DDL after the EntityManagerFactory has been
>   initialized, creating/updating all relevant tables. Note that the
>   exact semantics of this flag depend on the underlying persistence
>   provider. For any more advanced needs, specify the appropriate
>   vendor-specific settings as "jpaProperties".

Having the value `true` means that if the database tables don't exist or need to be updated, it will be done automatically. If the value is false, you will have to do it manually.

Comment: so in theory, if I make a change to an Entity (add a attribute that is mapped to a column that doesn't exist in the database), upon startup of the web app, Spring will automatically run the alter table statement and commit it to the DB?  I don't see that happening in my setup...